# In a Web API call, if the server's reply didn't get to the client, will the server know?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

A client, such as a C# program, invokes a server via its web API. The server process that is invoked does some database changes, then returns some data to the client, and the web API call finishes.

Suppose the response fails on its way to the client - for example the client dies and therefore the response can't be transmitted to the client.

In this case, will the server process get an exception from the operating system, so that it can rollback the database changes, or will the server happpily assume that the client has received the response, and commit the database changes?

The reason I am asking this, is that I don't want the server's database to be in a state that believes that the client has got the response, but the client hasn't. This will result in lost of sync between the client devices and the server.

Comment: In TCP protocol, the server waits for an acknowledgement from the receiver for each 'segment'. If the server doesn't receive the acknowledgement within a certain time, the segment will be retransmitted

Comment: Thanks for your response - but what if the client dies and the response can't be retransmitted? Will the server process get an exception?